# Which article should be used in this sentence?

Tags: articles

I have to fill the blank with an article (**a,an or the**)

**Copper is  _  useful metal**.

Metal is a noun and it is qualified by an adjective 'useful'. But I can't find any rule pertaining to this situation and hence I'm not sure which article would be suitable.

Please provide me the answer with an appropriate reason.

Comment: Why do you think both "an" and "a" are still in the running? The consonant sound at the beginning of "useful" should tell you than "an" is unacceptable.

Comment: Usually a word starting with a vowel would take "an": an apple, an egg, an Italian, an open door, an ugly duckling. But if the SOUND is like a consonant then it takes an "a": a unique (something), a eulogy. This is true even with the _names_ of the vowels: an a, an e, an i, an o, **a** U.

Comment: @katatahito Yes, I know it. So we are left with a and the, which is more suitable?

Comment: I've read your question on meta (-17) And you thought it was bad here... anyhoo, this looks like a homework question, in which case you should share what research you did to resolve the problem. Looking up metals or knowing that copper is a noun is minimal, and will not help you nor any future user, it is looking up "definite" vs "indefinite articles" that should help you resolve the dilemma. Then in a comment you say you know that "an" must be discarded, so why didn't you mention that in the question?

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/e/definite-vs-indefinite-articles/ and https://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-an-vs-the.htm

Comment: @MariLouA I’m thankful to you for coming over here from meta (-17) (this negative seventeen is quite funny), I was confused because I couldn’t see the role of definiteness or indefiniteness there. It is explained in answer which I was needing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **a** should be used because copper is one one example under the category of **useful metals** which also could include aluminum, iron, gold, silver, among others.

In isolation, that is the answer most speakers would choose

---

Long Answer: It depends on the circumstance. To give one example:

An engineer is talking to their apprentice through why copper is (surprisingly to the apprentice) the metal used for a specific application

> You would think steel would be used here, right? Most people do but this situation is different. **Copper is *the* useful metal**

This is a scenario where what is considered "useful" has been more narrowly defined, to where copper is the only member of the group (or at least the *most* useful of the members.) Therefore it is **the** metal as opposed to **a** metal.